# Regex too greedy; eats nearly all my rows

Tags: regex, cocoa, nsregularexpression

from some XML-data:

```
<Row A1:Height="17" ss:StyleID="s139">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">Title1</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="Print_Titles"/><NamedCell ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/><NamedCell
      ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s70"><Data ss:Type="String">Title2</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="Print_Titles"/><NamedCell ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/><NamedCell
      ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>
</Row>

<Row A2:Height="17" ss:StyleID="s139">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s69"><Data ss:Type="String">Title1</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="Print_Titles"/><NamedCell ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/><NamedCell
      ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s70"><Data ss:Type="String">Title2</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="Print_Titles"/><NamedCell ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/><NamedCell
      ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>
</Row>
....
```

Using regex I'm trying to find only the first row that contains cells with "Title1" and "Title2" in it.

```
-(NSString *)extractDataFromXMLString:(NSString *)xmlString{


NSString *headerPattern =
@" *<Row[^>]*>\n"
@" *<Cell[^>]*>.*Title1.*</Cell>\n"
@" *<Cell[^>]*>.*Title2.*</Cell>\n"
@" *</Row>";

NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *headerExpression = [NSRegularExpression 
    regularExpressionWithPattern:headerPattern                                                                      
options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive|NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators                                                                                  error:&error];


NSRange rangeOfFirstMatch = [headerExpression rangeOfFirstMatchInString:xmlString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [xmlString length])]

return [xmlString substringWithRange:rangeOfFirstMatch]
}
```

However I get the entire string returned
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing `.*` with `.*?` in your pattern should do the trick, though you should seriously consider using an actual xml parser instead of regular expressions for this.

Comment: I was working back from a larger XML-source and adding the ? worked for this small snippet of code but not for the bigger set of data. However you're right ofcourse about the XML-parsing, thanks for setting me straight.